# Epoxied garage floor not draining

Tags: water, garage, epoxy

My garage had a concrete floor that was pitted so I had a professional epoxy the floor. I believe they said the put down 2 coats totaling 1/8th inch thick. Now that it’s done, I have water pooled in one area of the garage from snow melting off my car.  One side of the garage is fine but about a third of the other side constantly has water pooled. I expected that the epoxy would self level and it would drain out the front. Should it drain like I expected it to?   The people who did it said I have a low spot and that I’d need to buy a squeegee.

Comment: Coating and leveling are two different things. And  it appears that you were told this by your applicators, so I can't see why you'd expect otherwise.

Comment: Because water didn’t pool prior to having the epoxy coating done and the floor didn’t appear to have a low spot prior.  Also the applicator did not explain that there was a difference between coating and leveling so based off all of this it was unexpected to now have this issue.

Comment: Uncoated concrete absorbs water. Coated concrete does not.

Comment: Doesn't self-leveling lead to a level (i.e. non-draining) surface? Drainage requires at least a slight slope.

Comment: Buy a squeegee is good advice.

Answer (score 7):

If your contract with the company that did the epoxy did not specifically address remediation of low spots or drainage issues, then you need to buy a squeegee.

Epoxy is not a leveling compound, and I know of no company that will advertise it as such. If you expected it to do so you were assumptive.
I believe you got what you paid for.